# Como que eu faço para mudar a propriedade 'filter: grayscale() ' com JS

Tags: javascript, css3

Estou tentanto fazer com que todas as imagens de um projeto meu fiquem cinza com um botão, ja criei a function() pra fazer isso, agora só estou em duvida de como eu altero o valor de grayscale com JS

```
function colorirImgs(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("container-align").style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` retorna um `HTMLCollection` que não contém a propriedade `style`. Para isso, você precisa iterar a função `getElementsByClassName`, mas também não é tão simples, porque ela não possui `forEach`, então você tem que converter ela para um array:

```js
function colorirImgs() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("container-align"))
    .forEach(e => e.style.filter = "grayscale(0)")
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container-align {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="colorirImgs()">
  Colorir imagens
</button>
<img class="container-align" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
<img class="container-align" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" />
<img class="container-align" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" />
```

Também pode ter o mesmo resultado com `for`:

```js
function colorirImgs() {
  const imagens = document.getElementsByClassName("container-align");
  for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
    imagens[i].style.filter = "grayscale(0)"
  }
}
```

Ou com [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("container-align")]
    .forEach(e => e.style.filter = "grayscale(0)")
```

Documentação do [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).